# How to add text in current cell without creating the circular reference error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add text in the current selected cell

My VBA function is :

```
Function AddText()
    ActiveCell.Value = "Hello World!"
End Function
```

But I'm getting following error when I call the function :

"There are one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly. This might cause them to calculate incorrectly. Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to different cells."

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

When using a function, you need to let the function return the value, not change the cell's value:

```
Function AddText()
    AddText = "Hello World!"
End Function
```

and then you can use it in a cell like so
`=AddText()`
which will show "Hello World!" in the cell you've typed it in.

Comment: You're too fast, BigBen! Being faster than me to edit my own answer, I'll be damned.